# Central Limit Theorem - Asymptotic approximation to sums of Poisson random variables and Binomial random variables

Tags: probability, solution-verification, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution, central-limit-theorem

**Question**:
Let $X_1, X_2, ...$ be a sequence of iid $\textrm{Poi}(5)$ variables. Let $Y_1, Y_2, ...$ be a sequence of iid $\textrm{Bin}(10,\dfrac{1}{2})$ variables. Define the sums $S_n = \sum_1^n X_i$ and $T_n = \sum_1^n Y_i$ for $i=1,2,...$.

Calculate asymptotic approximations to these quantities:
$$\mathbb{P}(5 n-\sqrt{n}<T_n<5 n + \sqrt n)$$ and $$\mathbb{P}(5 n-\sqrt{n}<S_n<5 n + \sqrt n).$$
Establish which is closer to 1 for large n.

**My attempt:**
I have:
$\mathbb{E}(S_n) = 5n$, $\mathbb{E}(T_n)=5n$, $\textrm{Var}(S_n)=5n$, $\textrm{Var}(T_n)=\dfrac{5}{2}n$.
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{5}}<\dfrac{S_n - 5 n}{\sqrt{5n}}< \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\approx 2\Phi\left(\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\right)-1.$$

Also, $$\mathbb{P}\left(\dfrac{-1}{\sqrt{5/2}}<\dfrac{T_n - 5 n}{\sqrt{5n/2}}< \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{5/2}}\right)\approx 2\Phi\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{5}}\right)-1.$$

Thus, $$\mathbb{P}(5 n-\sqrt{n}<T_n<5 n + \sqrt n)$$ is closer to 1 for large $n$.

Would this be correct? I am worried as I got numerical answers for the last part rather than an expression which tends to 1, which I am expecting due to the Weak Law of Large Numbers? Thank you.

Comment: Your method for solving this exercise looks to be correct. I dont know what your concern is about for the last part. For large n you have used the central limit theorem to get your answer, which is and should be numerical.

Comment: Thanks Curl. I had confused the limit theorems which I had learnt. I had a misunderstanding regarding the weak law of large numbers and the central limit theorem. Thank you for your help

Comment: It is probably true for all $n$.  The two distributions have the same mean, and the binomial distribution has half the variance and so is more likely to be in any given interval centred on the mean